# В каком процессе Android Studio происходит редактирование файлов проекта?

Tags: android-studio

Хочу найти какой процесс предложить добавить в исключени программы Caramba Switcher, или исключение для Punto Switcher. 
Какой процесс нужно внести в исключения чтобы автопереключение во время работы в студии не работало?

Пробовал основной процесс - studio64.exe , не помогло.

Comment: а все процессы студии вас не устроит? Вы опишите цель и причину почему мой вариант не подходит.

Comment: Можно же в исключения внести по имени окна, а не по процессу.